# How can change the phase of a sine wave (with visual feedback) whilst it is playing?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, phase

I’m trying to replicate a [famous experiment](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6535047_Simultaneous_cancellation_of_air_and_bone_conduction_tones_at_two_frequencies_Extension_of_the_famous_experiment_by_von_Bekesy) in which a sine wave delivered through headphones is cancelled by a sine wave of the opposite phase delivered through a bone conductor.

To achieve this experimentally, participants should be able to change phase of the bone conducted sine wave whilst the air conducted sine wave plays with fixed phase. In MATLAB, two pieces of code are necessary:

1. Ability for user input to change phase of a sine wave whilst the sine wave is playing
2. Visual feedback showing live updates with phase settings

I’m tackling these in turn.

1. **Change phase of sine wave**
   I’ve used the digital signal processing toolbox in MATLAB to create two sine wave system objects, with a phase separation of two pi radians. Both sine waves have unity amplitude. I’m planning to set user input to take a value between zero and two, multiply the amplitude of the second sine wave by the user input, and then add the two sine waves together and normalise them so that they once again have unity amplitude. I hope that this will alter the phase as desired. However, I need to check results visually to verify the behaviour is as I anticipate.

There might be a better way than this to alter phase. Or, maybe I've guessed wrong and my planned manipulation won't work (worried I might skew the sine wave). Please suggest a better approach if you can think of one!

[Note: phase is a nontunable property of sine wave system objects. If phase was a tunable property, altering the phase of the system object directly (by tuning the system object) would have been an obvious solution.]

2. **Visual feedback**
   I’ve tried to use dsp.TimeScope (I’m on MATLAB 2019a, so don't have the newer Timescope) but cannot find a way to obtain live updates of the sine wave as the user changes phase settings. Despite having frames set to update every 50 milliseconds, I can only see the updated sine wave in dsp.TimeScope when I stop the script running.

I thought of using live scripts and the plot function instead of dsp.TimeScope. Is doing so likely to be effective? Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Any tips on parts (1) or (2) would be greatly appreciated! I think this should be a simple piece of programming, and suspect that there is an elegant way to do it. However, I’m not at all sure what the best approach will be.

Comment: I should add for clarification, I'm using Psychtoolbox KbCheck to obtain the keyboard input. Intention is to use arrow keys to change phase.

Comment: Is there a way to use delay? Delay is very simple to code, generally, and your buffer would only need to have as many frames as there are in a single period. I've done this with Java. (Am working on an experiment on my own about pitch/timbre interactions.)

Comment: Delay could certainly work. However, I’m worried over how reliably the delay will be produced (e.g. is it based on the system clock? Or a filter?), and how I could test the effect of a delay on phase. If anything goes wrong, it could affect the entire experiment.

Comment: I've thought another approach. What might work is to use the audioDeviceWriter in the Digital System Processing toolbox. This creates data in “frames”, which are a user-specified number of samples. The frames are then passed to a buffer in the sound card. The sound card performs a digital to analogue conversion, sending the corresponding signal to the sound out port. As long as the buffer is refilled regularly with new frames, the audio will play out uninterrupted.

Comment: I’d generate the sine wave using the dsp.SineWave object in the Digital System Processing toolbox. If I can create a frame which corresponds exactly to an integer multiple of waveform periods (say, a 20 ms frame, which is 10 periods for a 500 Hz sine wave) then what I’d have to do is time phase resets to occur whenever a new frame of data is passed to the sound card. There should be enough time to do this while the buffer is full.

Comment: And if there isn’t, I can simply extend the frame length to create more time (the only downside of doing so is that a buffer size greater than 20 ms will be perceptible to the user – the system will seem to have a slight lag).

Comment: The challenge with this approach would be in programming the instruction it in such a way that it is bulletproof.

Comment: My supervisor suggested an alternative approach. Rather than playing continuously, different sine waves would play for a limited time (e.g. two seconds) and participants would use something called a two alternative forced choice procedure to choose between phase settings.

Comment: This approach can work. It’s likely to be quicker and easier to program, and therefore a safer choice. So, it’s likely to be what I’ll do. However, I’d still like to know how to change phase of sine waves while they are playing continuously! Grrr.

Comment: For delay strategy, assuming a stereo signal, just alter the frame data of the PCM. Can MathLab generate your .wav file from PCM? It is a simple matter to take PCM value on the left at frame X and copy it to frame X + (periodFrameCount) on the right. Only one file, so no synchronization issues. Frame counts are totally reliable for timing. (44100 fps, for example, A 440 has a period of about 100 frames, so to cancel, move value at frame 1000 L to 1050 R. Linear interpolation can be used for getting fractional values that are in between frames, for greater precision than 44100 fps.

Comment: PCM is pulse code modulation? I'm not sure MATLAB has built-in routines which directly enable PCM changes. I just checked and I found this code in File Exchange:

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28416-pulse-code-modulation

But it's from 2006. I'm a bit nervous about extending MATLAB in this way – using oldish code, and using MATLAB in a way for which it wasn't intended. With the kind of timing adjustments I need for this project, I think the implementation should be fairly low level (i.e. it's an instruction altering operation of the sound card). Can MATLAB do that?

Comment: It seems to me MATLAB lets you work directly with the sample data (aka pcm data). There may be conversion steps from the file bytes to the pcm per the audio format. But if they can plot audio files, you should be able to read and write what you need, directly. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-and-get-information-about-audio-files.html